# Getting error with SSL on dotnet Razor application - 'this ca root certificate is not trusted'

Tags: asp.net, .net, ssl, razor, razor-pages

I have put in a couple of commands in my startup.cs file which should enable me HTTPS access. The code I have is:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
```

I have tried to run this command also:

```
dotnet dev-certs https -v
```

But, that command tells me that I already have a certificate. My page redirects me from localhost:5000 to localhost:5001 but it is **not secure**.

When clicking 'not secure' in the url and clicking the certificate, I am getting the following window:

[image: Window Error]

I can't seem to find the issue at all and I have no idea how to fix it, does anybody have any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

A few things are missing from your Configure method. you might need to put things in place like, UseHttpsRedirection, etc.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler();
    }
    app.UseHsts(); //is a security feature to force SSL.
    app.UseAuthentication();//authentication middleware 
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Also you'd need to make a changes in the launchSettings.json file.

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
      "sslPort": 44300
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "YOUR-PROJECT": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5001"
    }
  }
}
```

pay attention to the "applicationUrl"(http and https url) and the "sslPort" (44300 - 44399)